# How can I include the java rxtx library into my Minecraft mod?

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, rxtx, minecraft-forge

How would you include the rxtx dlls in a minecraft forge mod I have no trouble whatsoever with the rxtxcomm.jar file but I cant include the root folder in the classpath (like normal) because then the game wont launch because of the duplicate mod (Im currently using eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // create a directory called libs in the directory where the build.gradle is
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
jar {
    // make in the directory where the build.gradle is a native folder
    // and put your dll's there.
    from('native') {
        into('org/sqlite/native')
        }
    }
 processResources
    {
    //... add this below what's already there under process resources.
    copy {
            from('/native')
            into('/org/sqlite/native')
        }
}
```

This combination of stuff works for me to add the sqlite jar and dll's to my who took my cookies jar.

Comment: Thanks alot, but sadly I have figured out another way, I have another program and it runs a server and the mod connects to that server and the server then relays it to the arduino via rxtx, I like it alot since I can easily have it work with terraria, csgo, arma, my own game, kerbal space program, war thunder, etc.